# Will I be refused a residence permit for having overstayed my Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, residency, latvia

My Schengen visa expired on 25 June 2014, but my residence permit will be issued on 15 July 2014 (I was supposed to get it before my visa expired but the person who deals with my residence permit is on holiday for one month which caused the application to be delayed).

Before my visa expired, I asked a clerk in the immigration office and was told that I simply need to pay a fine when I come to collect my residence permit, no more than 100 euros. So I decided to stay longer without visa (and overstayed) but I subsequently read on the internet and was told by friends it won't be that simple and that my residence permit might be refused because of me having overstayed my visa.

If you had a similar experience, can you please share with me? Or do you have another better idea about what to do in this situation?

Comment: What type of residence permit are you waiting for and from which country?

Comment: residence permit for paying property. country is Lativa

Comment: what means of There are more than two dozen countries in the Schengen area.?

Comment: @Zhang The Schengen area comprises 26 countries. They share a common visa policy for short stays but each of them has different rules regarding overstays or residence permits. Maybe someone with some experience of Latvia will be able to answer the question but do not assume that what you might have read about other Schengen countries automatically applies.

Comment: then what about my situation? what will happen to me when i come to collect my residence permit?

Comment: actually i got 2 answer from 2 persons in the immigration office. one person said I just need to pay for fine and it will be less than 100 euros. other one said it is very bad, they may not issue my residence card for this invalid visa. i don't know who shall i trust?

Comment: Yes I agree with you but I got different answer from different people in Latvian immigration office. so I am very confused which is truth? what should I do if they really may not issue my residence card because of my invalid visa?

Comment: Generally speaking, for anything as complicated and (presumably) important, you should hire a lawyer familiar with the issue and the local law.

Comment: I also asked a local lawyer and the lawyer said same thing as the first person i asked in immigration office like paying fine. but 2nd person from immigration office i asked in other time, he gave me totally different answer like they may not issue residence card.

Comment: Probably you got a receipt for your residence permit request, normally the receipt if valid only inside the country (meaning you can't go to other EU countries with that paper) until you get the response for your request (accepted or denied).

Comment: by the way Latvia (and other Schengen countries) offers this kind of residence permit to raise money (you buy the house and they give you the permit), will be a nonsense to get the permit refused.

Comment: I did get a receipt for my residence permit request from Latvian Immigration Office but I didn't know it is only valid in Latvia and unfortunately I am back to Germany already 2 weeks ago but nobody knows as there was no passport control and they even didn't look at my passport in airport since i did online check in. will it be a problem? also i am really very confused about different saying from different people in the Latvian Immigration Office, paying fine or not issue me residence card, which one is correct?

Comment: Yes I was confirmed that I didn't have any documents missing and they checked every single documents and said OK but the lady also said she doesn't know the final decision as it only can be decided the person who look into my documents but she is on holiday for one month which caused my visa expired.

Comment: currently you are in Germany or in Latvia?

Comment: Germany but there was no any records about my traveling within Schengen countries?

Comment: hope that you will not be checked when you back to Latvia, I hope that you carried with you the Latvia receipt, as I wrote normally this kind of receipt is not valid, but if German police border is aware of the situation (meaning waiting for the residence permit) maybe they will consider it valid. Explain the situation if they check you, don't advise them before.

Comment: I am concerned about why do they tell me different words in the Riga immigration office? paying fine or not issue residence card for me? which one is correct? this result is most important to me.

Comment: Surely this limbo has not dragged on for 6 months!

Comment: Hello guys, long time i haven't come to here. Ok..result is: i got residence permit 7 months ago without any problems! was very simple and easy as i thought..when i arrived their office, i have been told that my residence card was ready already, and i made a signature, then collected my card. so a whole process was less than 10 minutes. there was a big surprise for me is the issuing date of residence card was same date as my visa expiring date, so there was no any gap between visa and residence card. thank guys for your attention about this matter.